# Using URL Rewrite Middleware without changing address in Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently having an issue using URL rewrite Middleware.
When I rewrite the URL it changes the address in the browser to redirected URL but I want to show the provided URL in the address bar, not the URL to which it is redirected.

The current code that I am using is this:

```
    public class RedirectWwwRule : IRule
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; } = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
        public bool ExcludeLocalhost { get; set; } = true;

        public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            var host = request.Host;          
            string providedUrl = "", redirectUrl = "/";

            if (request.Path.Value.Length >= 2)
            {
                providedUrl = request.Path.Value.Substring(1, request.Path.Value.Length - 1);
                if (providedUrl.ToLower().Equals("home.html"))
                {
                    redirectUrl = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", "home", "index");
                }
                else if (providedUrl.ToLower().Equals("error.html"))
                {
                    redirectUrl = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", "home", "error");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
                return;
            }

            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = newPath;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
            // Do not continue processing the request        
        }
    }
```

**I think this code is redirecting instead of rewriting the URL.**
Please help me to achieve **rewriting**.

Comment: Could you please show us  config method on your startup file?

Comment: I am just adding this line above adding routes:
`app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RedirectWwwRule()));`

Comment: If you just rewrite the url,it would not shown on your browser address.

Comment: What I am missing here? For rewrite?